# SourceTree click ' terminal button' to switch terminal not work

Tags: macros, atlassian-sourcetree, iterm2

Mac : sierra 10.12.5
sourceTree: 2.6(123)
iTerm2: Build 3.0.15

when i use the top right button "terminal"(near Setting) to switch to my iTerm2. it crashed!
no matter i update to 2.6, it doesn't work!

[image]

Comment: I have this issue too! was able to open iTerm2 with applescript using the stuff here https://iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that you have updated iTerm 2 to v3.1.5 (or later). See that version's change log for fixes to crash conditions.
2. hard reboot and start again.
3. Contact support of Apple
4. No solution so far

Answer (score 0):

According to `/Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/iTerm2Helper.scpt`

```
set newWindow to (create window with profile \"Default\")
```

SourceTree will open iTerm2 with the profile named "Default", So you must make sure you have the profile named "Default" in iTerm2.

[iTerm2 profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EM5i.png)